# ¿Por qué no recibo información envíada de app de terminal Bluetooth a modulo HM-10 en arduino?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

Estoy intentando comenzar con el uso de bluetooth por medio de un modulo HM-10 y arduino UNO, estoy utilizando la app llamada "Serial Bluetooth Terminal" al parecer conecta correctamente con el dispositivo HM-10 pero a la hora de enviarle un "1" o "0" no lo recibe y por obviedad no lo demás que en mi programación arduino le estoy pidiendo que en este caso es encender un led.
El código arduino es el siguiente:

```
#define RX 11
#define TX 10
#define pinLED 13
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(TX, RX);

void setup() {

  bluetooth.begin(9600);
  bluetooth.println("Arduino Enabled, Bluetooth Test.");
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Arduino Enabled, Bluetooth Test.");
  pinMode(pinLED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  byte BluetoothData;  
  if (bluetooth.available() > 0) {

   switch (bluetooth.read()) {
    case '0':
      digitalWrite(pinLED, LOW);
      bluetooth.println("Apaga el LED");
      Serial.println("Apaga el LED");
      break;
    case '1':
      digitalWrite(pinLED, HIGH);
      bluetooth.println("Enciende el LED");
      Serial.println("Enciende el LED");
      break;
    default:
      bluetooth.println("Sin comando");
      Serial.println("Sin comando");
   }
 }
 delay(100);
}
```

Ojalá alguien pueda ayudarme he estado viendo preguntas similares y no son respondidas por lo regular, por el momento gracias.

Comment: ¿tienes bien conectado RX y TX?
se conectan cruzado https://felixmaocho.files.wordpress.com/2016/02/cable-cruzado.png lo otro que puede ser que el `case '0':` esta esperando un carácter cero (por las comillas simples) que en int seria un 48 intenta probar con `case 0:`,  no tengo el modulo de bluetooth para probar.

Comment: Era el RX y TX amigo gracias, sólo que ahora como estoy desarrollando mi propia aplicación para lograr comunicarme, estoy teniendo dificultades con saber como obtener el servicio UUID de mi bluetooth, si sabes algo de ellos te agradecería demasiado si puedes instruirme amigo.

Comment: No se como funcionan los bluetooth :).